# TagBuilder gone from MVC 3 beta to RC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What happened to the `TagBuilder` class between ASP.NET MVC 3 beta and RC?

When compiling my project I get the error:

> The type name 'TagBuilder' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

However that assembly does not exist in the GAC (nor in the *.NET* tab of the *Add References* dialog.)  A search of my HDD doesn't turn up a DLL with that name either.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM while trying to compile an ASP.NET MVC 2 project. This is a major breaking change, and it's disappointing that Microsoft did this. Now I can't do MVC 3 development on the same box or release any builds until we get all of our developers' machines (and servers) to have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed.

Comment: I had this trouble when upgrading a project from MVC2 to MVC3 using VS11. Had to clean, close and re-open the solution before the project would build without giving this error.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

On my install of the RC, that assembly lives here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll
```

Comment: Ah thanks.  I searched with the wrong filename.  Apparently both you and Darin answered at exactly the same time: `2010-11-24 08:32:50Z`.  I've accepted your answer because your path worked on my 64 bit OS, and to support the underdog :)

Answer (score 20):

It was moved to the `System.Web.Pages.dll` assembly:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to upgrade from mvc3 beta and luckily stumbled across this. :P

Comment: You probably meant the System.Web.WebPages.dll

Answer (score 3):

FYI: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll

is where it got installed by default on my Windows 7 Ultimate Box

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2012, I added this reference by going to the Reference Manager for the project (right click on References in the project and select *Add Reference*). Filtering by Assemblies and then Extensions (that is the important part), and adding System.Web.WebPages.

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2010 SP1, Microsoft added a new feature to copy these assemblies locally into your project (and source control). This way, the application can run on servers without needing to install MVCx. Right-click on the project, and choose "Add Deployable Dependencies..." and select the MVC checkbox. System.Web.WebPages will be pulled into your project.

Check out this article here that goes into more detail: [Adding-mvc-dependencies-to-project](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/06/adding-mvc-dependencies-to-project-for.html)